# Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object on LanguageComponent

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies

I am having this line in my CakePHP code: `$language = $this->Cookie->read('language');`

and I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object in
C:\Apache24\htdocs\cake\app\Controller\Component\LanguageComponent.php on line 27
```

Here is my **LanguageComponent.php** code

```
<?php

//App::Import('Component', 'Cookie'); 
class LanguageComponent extends Object {

    public $controller = null;
    public $components = array('Cookie');
    public $languages = array();

    public function initialize($controller) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        if (empty($languages)) {
            $this->languages = Configure::read('Config.languages');
        }
        $this->set();
    }

    public function set($language = null) {
        $saveCookie = false;
        if (empty($language) && isset($this->controller)) {
            if (!empty($this->controller->params['named']['lang'])) {
                $language = $this->controller->params['named']['lang'];
            } elseif (!empty($this->controller->params['url']['lang'])) {
                $language = $this->controller->params['url']['lang'];
            }
            if (!empty($language)) {
                $saveCookie = true;
            }
        }
        if (empty($language)) {
            $language = $this->Cookie->read('language');
            if (empty($language)) {
                $saveCookie = true;
            }
        }
        if (empty($language) && !array_key_exists($language, $this->languages)) {
            $language = Configure::read('Config.language');
        }
        Configure::write('Config.language', $language);
        if ($saveCookie) {
            $this->Cookie->write('language', $language, false, '1 year');
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Where could the problem be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Wrong parent class

Compare the code in the question:

```
class LanguageComponent extends Object {
```

To [any core component](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Controller/Component):

```
class AuthComponent extends Component {
```

Extending the wrong class means that none of the [component constructor logic](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Controller/Component.php#L77) is invoked, and [the way components are loaded on first access](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Controller/Component.php#L95) will not be available.

#### In the process of upgrading?

This is possibly because the language component was originally written for 1.x - the parent class for components changed when 2.x was released. As mentioned in [the 2.0 migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#components):

> Component is now the required base class for all components.

Comment: Thanks ad7six. that makes much sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public $controller = null;
    public $languages = array();
    public $Cookie;

    public function initialize($controller) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        if (empty($languages)) {
            $this->languages = Configure::read('Config.languages');
        }
        $this->set();
    }

    public function set($language = null) {
        $this->Cookie = new CookieComponent(new ComponentCollection());
        $saveCookie = false;
        if (empty($language) && isset($this->controller)) {
            if (!empty($this->controller->params['named']['lang'])) {
                $language = $this->controller->params['named']['lang'];
            } elseif (!empty($this->controller->params['url']['lang'])) {
                $language = $this->controller->params['url']['lang'];
            }
            if (!empty($language)) {
                $saveCookie = true;
            }
        }
        if (empty($language)) {
            $language = $this->Cookie->read('language');
            if (empty($language)) {
                $saveCookie = true;
            }
        }
        if (empty($language) && !array_key_exists($language, $this->languages)) {
            $language = Configure::read('Config.language');
        }
        Configure::write('Config.language', $language);
        if ($saveCookie) {
            $this->Cookie->write('language', $language, false, '1 year');
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Thus produces this error: Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to CookieComponent::__construct() must be an instance of ComponentCollection, none given..Fatal error: Call to a member function getController() on a non-object in C:\Apache24\htdocs\cake\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\CookieComponent.php on line 177

Comment: This is not the right way to fix your component @mashzo

Comment: Yes, in fact AD7six answer is the correct one. This here is simply the wrong way to do it for multiple reasons.

Answer (score -1):

This revised code works without any warning.

```php
App::Import('Component', 'Cookie');

class LanguageComponent extends Component {

    public $controller = null;
    public $languages = array();
    public $Cookie;

    public function initialize(Controller $controller) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        if (empty($languages)) {
            $this->languages = Configure::read('Config.languages');
        }
        $this->set();
    }

    public function set($language = null) {
        $this->Cookie = new CookieComponent(new ComponentCollection());
        $saveCookie = false;
        if (empty($language) && isset($this->controller)) {
            if (!empty($this->controller->params['named']['lang'])) {
                $language = $this->controller->params['named']['lang'];
            } elseif (!empty($this->controller->params['url']['lang'])) {
                $language = $this->controller->params['url']['lang'];
            }
            if (!empty($language)) {
                $saveCookie = true;
            }
        }
        if (empty($language)) {
            $language = $this->Cookie->read('language');
            if (empty($language)) {
                $saveCookie = true;
            }
        }
        if (empty($language) && !array_key_exists($language, $this->languages)) {
            $language = Configure::read('Config.language');
        }
        Configure::write('Config.language', $language);
        if ($saveCookie) {
            $this->Cookie->write('language', $language, false, '1 year');
        }
    }

}
```